# Relationship between an entity and non entity classes

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa

I've a class named LastPost. It is a non entity class and its functionality is to fetch some data from already existing tables through a raw query which mean the LastPost class doesn't have a table on its own.

```
@Setter
@Getter
public class LastPost {
    private int topicId;
    private Integer pageNumber;
    private Integer lastReplyId;
    private String topicTitle;
    private String shortTopicTitle;
    private int userId;
    private String username;
    private LocalDateTime lastPostDateTime;
}
```

In my Forum entity class I have the following attribute:

```
@Transient
private LastPost lastPost;
```

So how can I fetch a result set from a raw query and store it into a LastPost object so it can be automatically retrieved whenever a Forum object retrieved? (Like relationship).

Comment: The simplest way would be to create a DB view and map it onto an `@Immutable` entity

Comment: Why @Immutable? LastPost is a non-entity class which means it doesn't have a table. I want to execute a complex query and store the result inside LastPost object in Forum entity class.

Comment: If you create a view for your query, the entity backed by this view will not be editable for obvious reasons. If you then change anything in `LastPost`, Hibernate will try to persist the changes anyway, leading to an error (unless you mark the `LastPost` as `@Immutable`)

Comment: Thank you @crizzis, Your comments were very helpful to find the solution.